# Prove that $\exists y\in V$ so that the set {${u+y:u\in U}$} is a subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ a vector space over a field $F$, and let $v,w\in V$ so that $v\neq w$.

Define $U=${${(1-t)v+tw: t\in F}$}. Prove that $\exists y\in V$ so that the set {${u+y:u\in U}$} is a subspace of $V$

Can you give me a hint please? I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: It will be clear with a drawing. Basically, $U$ is the line passing through $v$ and $w$.

Comment: @user128422 Recall what a set of the form $(1-t)v + tw$ looks like, and the term for such a set.

Answer (score 1):

**Geometrical Intuition:** In general, the set of all points of the form $(1-t)v+tw$ is a **line**. We know that a line that does not go through the origin is not a subspace of a Euclidean space, while a line that goes through the origin **is** a subspace.

So we should choose $y$ so that the set of points of the form $y+(1-t)v+tw$ goes through the origin. There are many choices for $y$. It can be the negative of any point on our line. We can for example choose $y=-v$, or $y=-w$, or if you like symmetry you can try for $y=-\frac{1}{2}(v+w)$.

Now that we have found reasonable candidates, we need to check that the geometric intuition is correct, that we do indeed have a subspace. Verification of the axioms (closure under multiplication by a scalar, closure under addition) is mechanical.

Comment: Is it correct to choose a general $-u_t$ as I had originally thought?

Comment: It is definitely correct, the negative of any point on the line will do. I just have a personal preference for concreteness, if concreteness is achievable.

Answer (score 0):

Is $U$ a subspace of $V$ by itself? (specifically: is $-v\in U$? is $-w\in U$) If not, what is "missing" or "extra" and can this be eliminated by clever choice of $y$?